# Setting the Style in qml Qt

Tags: qt, qml, styling

I want to set the Style for my elements in qml. For that, I want to use a style like Material Style. Using the example which can be found under:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
   visible: true

   Material.theme: Material.Dark
   Material.accent: Material.Purple

   Column {
       anchors.centerIn: parent

       RadioButton { text: qsTr("Small") }
       RadioButton { text: qsTr("Medium");  checked: true }
       RadioButton { text: qsTr("Large") }
     }
}
```

Gives me the result seen in the image I attached. 
No matter which Style I use, nothing changes.

I am currently using the newest free Qt version under a Windows 10 Os.

Can anyone help me?
And is it possible to globally overwrite a Style and make an own Style, simply in QML.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#detailed-description) points out:

> To run an application with the Material style, see [Using Styles in Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls).

There are several ways to set the style in Qt Quick Controls 2:

1. [Using QQuickStyle in C++](http://Using%20QQuickStyle%20in%20C++):

   - add `QT += quickcontrols2` in your .pro and use `#include <QQuickStyle>` and `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");` in main.cpp
2. [Command line argument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#command-line-argument):

   - You can run from the console/CMD by adding the argument: `./your_executable -style material`.
   - If you use Qt Creator you can go to Projects-> Build & Run-> Run and in Command line arguments add: `-style material`.

[image]

3. [Environment variable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#environment-variable):

   - You can run from the console/CMD: `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE=material ./your_executable`
   - If you are using Qt Creator you can add it in the section Projects-> Build & Run-> Run-> Run Environment.

   [image]

   - or add `qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE", "material");` in main.cpp.
4. [Configuration file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#configuration-file):

   The **qtquickcontrols2.conf** file must be created:

   ```
   [Controls]
   Style=Material
   ```

   and must be in a qresource:

   ```xml
   <RCC>
       <qresource prefix="/">
           <file>main.qml</file>
           <file>qtquickcontrols2.conf</file>
       </qresource>
   </RCC>
   ```

Comment: The problem was me edeting the wrong project. Thanks a lot! Sometimes the problem sits between the ears. :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the style from C++ as well. See this [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickstyle.html#details).

So in you main add `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");`